# How to get 2 Character Country name using longitude and longitude android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I can get the longitude and longitude android. And now I want to get the short country name against it. How to do that? I also have country code... All I want is to show short country name e.g "UK" , "SG" etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a web-service that give 2 digit country code along with temperature.
Its very simple

http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=31.50766766,74.33741188000002